# Allow Permalinks to Work with and without Hyphens

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

Is there a way that I can change my .htaccess file to allow the user to go to a permalink with or without the hyphen? For example:

I have a page: `http://example.com/parent/two-words`

To get to that page, I'd like to be able to type in any of the following:

```
example.com/parent/two-words
example.com/parent/twowords
example.com/two-words
example.com/twowords
```

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using the plugin "Safe Redirects Manager" to redirect any /twowords/ to /two-words/ as necessary.